# How to return QVariant type array

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qvariant

I am recently creating a model for qml with c++, but I face a problem when returning a QVariant type empty array. How should I define my return statement?

```
switch (role) {
case NameRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("AAAAA"));
case LevelRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("1"));
case ParentRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("null"));
case SublevelRole:
    return ???// I would like to return an empty array
}
```

Comment: In my qml, I want to do something like this: objModel.append({"name":input2.text,"level":0,"parent":"null","subNode":[]}) which subNode is the empty array I want to create.

Comment: I want to use subNode to store second level of listmodels, I am not sure what type it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QVariantList`:

```
switch (role) {
case NameRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("AAAAA"));
case LevelRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("1"));
case ParentRole:
    return QVariant(QStringLiteral("null"));
case SublevelRole:
    return QVariantList();
}
```